# Why is this function still using memory after execution?

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
$worked = null;
unset($worked);
$mem = memory_get_usage();
$worked = $worker -> work($a, $b);
print_r($worked);
echo 'MEM: '.(memory_get_usage() - $mem), PHP_EOL;
```

Neither `$a` nor `$b` is passed by reference.

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [aa] => Array
        (
            [11] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [33] => 18
        )

    [bb] => Array
        (
            [11] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [33] => 18
        )

    [cc] => Array
        (
            [11] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [33] => 81
        )

    [dd] => Array
        (
            [11] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [33] => 81
        )

)
MEM: 222288
```

Variable `$worked` is just a small array that shouldn't take up **222KB** at all. It seems memory used by the execution of `$worker -> work()` method is not freed up?

Why? I thought returning from a function would destroy everything inside?

The above code is in a loop with thousands of executions per PHP run and it keeps piling up the memory usage and not freeing it up at all hurling towards an out of memory fatal error.

How can I force it free up the memory after returning from the method?

Answer (score 0):

The prove that the memory is piling up is not done by your code.
Try it like this and please report the result:

```
$worked = null;
$worked = $worker -> work($a, $b);
$mem = memory_get_usage();
print_r($worked);
unset($worked);
echo 'MEM 1: '.$mem, PHP_EOL;
echo 'MEM 2: '.memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: New results as per your code: `MEM 1: 5849488`
`MEM 2: 5847608`

Comment: Your $worker seem to take 1880 Byte, thats ~1.5 KB. But it's freed if you use my code.

Comment: No, it's not freed up. Put this `$mem = memory_get_usage();` before work() and the results are: `MEM 1: 5627200` `MEM 2: 5847608`

Comment: Memory is less by 5847608 - 5627200 = 220408 after execution and returning from the work() method. It doesn't seem freed up to me.

Comment: you can check it in the loop with 100 executions? If it's really piling up each time you had to destroy "worker" each time and instantiate it new, or use work as static function, perhaps that's behaving different.

Comment: class worker {
 public function work($a,$b){
  return array(
   'aa' => $a*$a,
   'ab' => $a*$b,
   'bb' => $b*$b
  );
 }
}
echo 'Memory before: '.memory_get_usage(). PHP_EOL;
$worker = new worker;
for ($m=0;$m<100;$m++){
 echo '<pre>';
 $mem0 = memory_get_usage();
 for ($n=1;$n<101;$n++){
  $mem = memory_get_usage();
  $worked = null;
  $worked = $worker -> work($n, ($n*$m));
  echo 'MEM: '.(memory_get_usage() - $mem), PHP_EOL;
  unset($worked);
 }
}
unset($worker);
echo 'Memory end: '.memory_get_usage(). PHP_EOL;

Comment: In that code in the comment before the end memory value is a bit higher but only a few byte. So I can't reproduce what you write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134542/discussion-between-kavoir-com-and-david).